# Math conditional statement resulting in nothing.

Tags: math, conditional-statements, statements

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = 1;

    System.out.println(" Enter a math operation: ");
    String expr = input.next();

    int pos = expr.indexOf("-");

    if ( pos > 0) {
        if (pos == expr.indexOf("+")) {
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, pos));
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring( pos + x , expr.length()));
        System.out.println( op1 + op2);
        } else 
        if (pos == expr.indexOf("-")) {
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, pos));
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring( pos + x , expr.length()));
        System.out.println( op1 - op2);
        } else
        if (pos == expr.indexOf("/")) {
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, pos));
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring( pos + x , expr.length()));
        System.out.println( op1 / op2); 
        } else 
        if (pos == expr.indexOf("%")) {
        int op1 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, pos));
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring( pos + x , expr.length()));
        System.out.println( op1 % op2);
        } 
        else {
        System.out.println(" Invalid operation ");
            }
        }       
}
```

}
This compiles, but I'm having a hard time doing the initializing the pos = expr.inexOf();. How would i go about this so that my if statements start working and are able to work with the string? thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with int pos = expr.indexOf("-");
am sure if u give the input as "25-20"it would work.
U will have to run a loop to find the correct operator first.